# Is there a way to stop word wrapping of a word with a dash in it? (i.e. eye-opening)

Tags: android, textview

I'm coding in Android right now and I want to keep a word, lets say "eye-opening" together when it word wraps. 
For Example:

```
| Going to SF was an eye- |
| opening experience      |
```

I don't want "eye-opening" to be split. I want it to be kept together like this:

```
| Going to SF was an      |
| eye-opening experience  |
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I doubt it. I do not see any option directly on `TextView` to control that, and there is no `CharacterStyle` that you could use that seems to control that.

Comment: thanks! the link kabuko provided solved my problem